# UpsetR How to fix: Image being cut off when trying to export

Tags: r, ggplot2, upsetr, upsetplot

I am using the UpsetR package to create a chart showing overlaps between different populations. However, when the plot is created it cuts off the numbers on the left-hand side bars and a bit of the set size title, I have tried adjusting the text size and the scale, but no combination seems to solve the problem. Please see my code below (originally source was an article about "hacking UpsetR" and I adjusted to my project, so not all the comments are my mine)

```
#read in analytic
plot_df <- data.frame(UE_UpsetR)

#look at colnames and what the data look like
colnames(plot_df)
head(plot_df, 5)

#This is a legend to the text_scale_options entries below.
#Text scale options are:
#c(intersection size title (Counts of Patterns of Conditions), 
#   intersection size tick labels (numbers up vertical y-axis), 
#   set size title (Counts by Single Chronic Condition), 
#   set size tick labels (numbers across x-axis), 
#   set names (disease names), 
#   numbers above bars)

#I created different options so I could see which ones I liked best
text_scale_options1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0.75, 1)
#text_scale_options2 <- c(1.3, 1.3, 1, 1, 2, 0.75)
#text_scale_options3 <- c(1.5, 1.25, 1.25, 1, 2, 1.5)

#setting colors
#this can also be done with hexadecimal
main_bar_col <- c("violetred4")
sets_bar_col <- c("turquoise4")
matrix_col <- c("slateblue4")
shade_col <- c("wheat4")

#I called it "1" because I anticipated others
#but never needed them
mb_ratio1 <- c(0.55,0.45)

#This is the vector of variables to be graphed
#They are the colnames of the plot_df.
#I suppose I could have automated this, but I fought with this code a lot.
#Importantly, if you want these labels to be different,
#you have to change the column names in the df.

set_vars <- c("MTS", "HSH", "PID", "TGWoman", "TGMan","TGOther")

#these are the libraries you need
library(UpSetR)
library(ggplot2)

upset(plot_df, 
      sets = set_vars,
  
      mainbar.y.label = "KP OVerlaps", 
      sets.x.label = "Absolute KP population Counts",
      order.by = "freq",
      number.angles = 0,
      point.size = 2, 
      line.size = 1,
      text.scale=text_scale_options1,
      set_size.show = TRUE,
      main.bar.color = main_bar_col,
      sets.bar.color = sets_bar_col,
      matrix.color = matrix_col,
      shade.color = shade_col,
     
      )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.